# не могу адаптировать хедер

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Помогите разобраться с адаптацией хедера, пробовал через медиа-запросы, но тоже не получается

```
<header class="head_bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="logo navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
                        <span class="sr-only">Открыть навигацию</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>              
                    </button>
                    <div class=" navbar-logo">
                        <div class="navbar navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="" href="#">069842020</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">COMANDA APEL</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">RO <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">RU</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">EN</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="logotip col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                            <img src="images/logo_one.png" class="img-responsive im_left " alt="">&nbsp;
                            <img src="images/logo_two.png" class="img-responsive im_right" alt="">  
                            <div class="text">
                                    <h1>BMW<br> X5</h1>
                                    <h2>INCONFUNDABIL</h2>
                                <div class="btn">
                                    VEZI OFERTA
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="indent-header"></div>
    </header>

header.head_bg{
    background: url(../images/head_bg.png) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

div.indent-header{
    min-height: 267px;
}

div.logo{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.fon4ik {
  background-image: url(https://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/f2BpWgnVgmo/mqdefault.jpg);
  /* Путь к фоновому изображению */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* Фиксируем фон веб-страницы */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  /* Современные браузеры */
}
```

```html
<body class='fon4ik'></body>
```

Вот решение, попробуй растянуть.

Answer (score 0):

Если после header нет больше элементов, то лучше применить background к body, если необходимо растянуть header на всю высоту экрана, то можно применить

```
height: 100vh; /* высота секции равна высоте области просмотра */
```

Подробнее: [habr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/243161/)